# How does Youtube webcam recording work? Other webcam recording solutions?

Tags: flash, youtube, webcam, recording

Which flash server does youtube use for http://www.youtube.com/my_webcam ? Is it just FMS? 
I'm asking because I have to implement a webcam recording application, and youtube one's the best I've seen so far. Great video quality and perfect audio sync.

For now I'm using rtmplite as flash server http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/ but the results aren't satisfactory, frequent out of sync audio and poor video quality.

So I'm thinking to give Wowza a shot: did anybody try it with good webcam recording quality and quasi-perfect audio sync?

Also, if you have any other suggestions on how to create a reliable webcam recording application/server, I'll be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Wowza for streaming live signals to an other server and loved it. Its quite easy to implement and quick. 
You can setup the bitrate for the file that you save yourself, so the quality is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

We've tried using HDFVR with Wowza media server. Results are great! Video+Audio Sync.